# Python multiprocessing limiting to 10% per core?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multithreading

I have a loop that I've been trying to speed up. I noticed that Python was only using a single core, so I imported the multiprocessing package and set up a pool. Now the whole process is distributed over a number of cores but they seem to be limited to ~10 %.

Is this expected/optimal? Or is there a way to utilise a more from each core?

[image: htop screenshot]

Code:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

//...more code here...

pool = ThreadPool(os.cpu_count())
pool.starmap(getSubject, zip(range(1, Nsub)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

ps. Before using `Pool` htop would show one core at 100 % and the others at ~0 %.

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` is a **thread** pool. Due to GIL you won't use multiple cores to the fullest. Change it to `multiprocessing.Pool` if you wish to use processes instead.

Note that the total usage of cores also depends on what exactly `getSubject` does. If you are doing some synchronization (e.g. locking) then you might see loss of performance as well.